# Guaranteeing mutex safety with async signals

Tags: c, synchronization, signals, posix

First, I am aware that the mutexes are not considered async-safe normally. This question concerns the use of `sigprocmask` to make mutexes safe in a multithreaded program with async signals and signal handlers.

I have some code conceptually like the following:

```
struct { int a, b; } gvars;

void sigfoo_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    if(gvars.a == 42 || gvars.b == 13) {
        /* run a chained signal handler */
    }
}

/* called from normal code */
void update_gvars(int a, int b) {
    gvars.a = a;
    gvars.b = b;
}
```

`gvars` is a global variable which is too large to fit in a single `sig_atomic_t`. It is updated by normal code and read from the signal handler. The controlled code is a chained signal handler, and so it must run in signal handler context (it may use `info` or `context`). Consequently, all accesses to `gvars` have to be controlled via some sort of synchronization mechanism. Complicating matters, the program is multithreaded, and any thread may receive a `SIGFOO`.

**Question:** By combining `sigprocmask` (or `pthread_sigmask`) and `pthread_mutex_t`, is it possible to *guarantee* synchronization, using code like the following?

```
struct { int a, b; } gvars;
pthread_mutex_t gvars_mutex;

void sigfoo_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    /* Assume SIGFOO's handler does not have NODEFER set, i.e. it is automatically blocked upon entry */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gvars_mutex);
    int cond = gvars.a == 42 || gvars.b == 13;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gvars_mutex);

    if(cond) {
        /* run a chained signal handler */
    }
}

/* called from normal code */
void update_gvars(int a, int b) {
    sigset_t set, oset;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGFOO);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &oset);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gvars_mutex);
    gvars.a = a;
    gvars.b = b;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gvars_mutex);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oset, NULL);
}
```

The logic goes as following: within `sigfoo_handler`, `SIGFOO` is blocked so it cannot interrupt the `pthread_mutex_lock`. Within `update_gvars`, `SIGFOO` cannot be raised in the current thread during the `pthread_sigmask`-protected critical region, and so it can't interrupt the `pthread_mutex_lock` either. Assuming no *other* signals (and we can always block any other signals that could be problematic), the lock/unlocks should always proceed in a normal, uninterruptible fashion on the current thread, and the use of lock/unlock should ensure that other threads don't interfere. Am I right, or should I avoid this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I found this paper https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/rego/cs543/threads/signals.pdf that discusses running AS-unsafe code in sig handlers safely by

1. masking out signals in AS-unsafe blocks of normal-context code (explored as less efficient) OR
2. protecting AS-unsafe blocks of normal-context code with a global sig_atomic volatile flag that prevents the AS-unsafe code in the handler from being entered if set (explored as efficient)

This approach satisfies the part of the POSIX standard that says that 
calling AS-unsafe functions in sig-handlers is only deemed unsafe if the sighandler interrupts an AS-unsafe function (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03 :  scroll down to the 1st paragraph after the function list)

I think what you're toying with here is essentially a more fine-grained version of this idea, since you're not trying to prevent

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&gvars_mutex);
int cond = gvars.a == 42 || gvars.b == 13;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&gvars_mutex);
```

run from a sig-handler from clashing with *any* AS-unsafe code but rather just with this same/similar AS-unsafe code dealing with this mutex and these variables.

Unfortunately, POSIX only seems to have a code-only concept of signal-safety: a function is either safe or unsafe, regardless of its arguments.

However, IMO, a semaphores/mutex has no good reason to operate on any data or OS handles other than those contained in the mutex/semaphore they're passed, so I think calling `sem_wait(&sem)`/`pthread_mutex_lock(&mx);` from a signal handler ought to be safe if it's guaranteed to never clash with a `sem_wait`/`pthread_mutex_lock` to the same mutex, even though the POSIX standard technically says it shouldn't be safe (counter-arguments more than welcome).

Comment: Well, my argument that you're correct is more or less "we used it in production and nothing broke" :D. But, of course, any correctness could just be chalked up to luck (e.g. kernel that happens to behave the right way, libc that behaves the right way, etc.) rather than being strictly correct according to the standards.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously know you're into undefined behavior territory with your mention of sig_atomic_t. That being said, the only way I can see this exact example not working on modern unix-like systems is if the signal was set up with SA_NODEFER.

The mutex is enough to ensure proper synchronization between different threads (including the signal handler being run in another thread) and the sigmask will prevent the signal handler in this thread recursing the mutex.

That being said, you're in deep water with locks inside signal handlers. One signal handler might be safe enough, but if you had two signal handlers doing the same trick with different locks you end up with lock ordering deadlocks. This can be somewhat mitigated by applying process sigmasks instead of thread sigmasks. A simple debugging fprintf in the signal handler will definitely violate lock ordering, for example.

I would back away and redesign my application because stuff like this in a signal handler is a sign it's getting too complex and too easy to break. Signal handlers touching one sig_atomic_t are the only defined thing in the C standard because of the exploding complexity of getting anything else right.

Comment: If the signal is setup with `SA_NODEFER`, then I should be able to use `sigprocmask` within the handler itself in the same way, no?

Comment: Also, process sigmasks are out of the question, since using `sigprocmask` simultaneously from two threads is definitely a no-no. I suspect that the best way to deal with it would be to block all signals in the thread sigmask if there were multiple signal handlers.

Comment: I would redesign the application if I could, obviously, but there are very good reasons why something like this is necessary in my case.